# Phoenix where to defimpl Plug.Exception

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to extend an existing exception in Phoenix.

I've seen from the docs to do this:

```
defimpl Plug.Exception, for: Ecto.NotSingleResult do
  def status(_exception), do: 404
end
```

But where does this go?

Also, I have two pipelines, one for :browser, one for :api
Is it possible to extend in one pipeline and not the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put the `defimpl` for the `Plug.Exception` protocol wherever you want, as long as the file it's in is loaded by Mix (e.g., files in `lib` or  `web`). For example, you can create `lib/my_app/plug_exception_implementations.ex` with this content:

```
defimpl Plug.Exception, for: Ecto.NotSingleResult do
  def status(_exception), do: 404
end

# other `defimpl Plug.Exception`s here if needed
```

Once you define the implementation of a protocol for a data type, it's global so it would be defined for both pipelines.